# SimpleDateFormat format date between to dates issue

Tags: java

I need to calculate period between two dates, one date is now. And I'm using `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting date.

```
public String getPeriod(Date endDate) {
    String format;
    Date now = new Date();
    long period  = endDate.getTime() - now.getTime();

    if (now.after(endDate)) {
        return "passed";
    } else {
        if (period < 1000 * 60 * 60)
            format = "m'M' s'S'";
        else if (period  < 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
            format = "k'H' m'M'";
        else
            format = "'Too much'";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return formatter.format(new Date(period)) + " / for testing - " + period / 3600000 + " hours";
    }
}
```

As a result I have following input for example if `endDate` equals `Wed Nov 12 13:30:02 EET 2014 (EST)`:

```
1 H 36 M / for testing - 22 hours
```

As you can see my test calculation and format's method result do not match. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The java.util.Date class is a bit of a mess, for the future I would look for an alternative. The java.util.Calandar class is a real mess too, I would look into Joda Time :)

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is for formatting a `Date` - a point in time. A difference between two times is *not* a point in time. You shouldn't be using it for that.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is due to the timezone. For example, in my case, given as the parameter the time that would be in an hour, I get 3H as output, because the date would be Thu Jan 01 03:00:00 EET 1970. Notice the EET (I'm from Eastern Europe).

Your code would work if you'd notify java to use GMT time, as it says in the new Date(long) description:

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Also, keep in mind that Date does not give perfect results. Using programatically determined dates exactly 1h appart (no millies / minutes difference), date calculations give an offset of 59 minutes, 59 seconds and 999 milies. If you require more exact values, you should use nanoseconds.

However, the other commenters are right. You should not use Java Date / Calendar in such a way, as it is a bug factory (this is only one corner case). You should check out other libraries (such as yoda time), or if you only need simple calculations such as this, do it yourself.

Hope it helps.